# How to apply a function with if statement in ddply or any kind of apply()?

Tags: r, if-statement, plyr

First let's generate some sample data and install `plyr` and `data.table` package:

```
library("plyr", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
library("data.table", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.1")
x<-seq(1:12)  
y<-rep(seq(1:4),3)
z<-c(rep("a",6),rep("b",6))  
t<-rep(seq(2005,length.out=6),2)
df<-data.table(t,x,y,z)
setkey(df,z,t)
```

this will yield a table:

```
       t  x y z
 1: 2005  1 1 a
 2: 2006  2 2 a
 3: 2007  3 3 a
 4: 2008  4 4 a
 5: 2009  5 1 a
 6: 2010  6 2 a
 7: 2005  7 3 b
 8: 2006  8 4 b
 9: 2007  9 1 b
10: 2008 10 2 b
11: 2009 11 3 b
12: 2010 12 4 b
```

Now the job is: separate this data.frame into two small data set according to z. in each set, if `y > lag(y,k=1)`(i.e y>previous y). then apply function `i=y/lag(y,k=1)`, otherwise, apply function `i=-y/lag(y,k=1)`.

The approach I tried is following:

```
#####define a function f
f<-function(x,y)
{ if (y>lag(y,k=1)) {i<-y/lag(y,k=1)}
  else{i<--y/lag(y,k=1)}
  return (i)
}
#######using ddply to apply function to subset
v<-ddply(df,.(z),summarize,i=f(x,y))
```

However this will return error massages saying:

```
Error in attributes(column) <- a : 
  invalid time series parameters specified
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (y > lag(y, k = 1)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (y > lag(y, k = 1)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I think I made some mistake during the coding and more importantly, it seems that my if statement doesn't looping in the function. Anyone have any idea how to correct this problem??

Thank you very much for your help in advance!!!

UPdate:

The desired result is something like this:

```
t x y z         i
1: 2005 1 1 a  na
2: 2006 2 2 a  2.000000
3: 2007 3 3 a  1.500000
4: 2008 4 4 a  1.333333
5: 2009 5 1 a -0.250000
6: 2010 6 2 a  2.000000
1: 2005  7 3 b  na
2: 2006  8 4 b  1.333333
3: 2007  9 1 b -0.250000
4: 2008 10 2 b  2.000000
5: 2009 11 3 b  1.500000
6: 2010 12 4 b  1.333333
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Ok.. I found that I made some mistake in the function when asking the question but I don't know how to edit it. The x in the function is useless and   it can be removed(though the problem remains the same)....

Comment: Is there a reason you created a data table instead of a data frame?  You don't use any data.table syntax in your code. Please also show the desired result

Comment: do the answer satisfies you?

Comment: Hi Colonel,Sorry for the late reply . I think this could work but is that possible to replicate things with ddply? I hope to apply the function inside the group but don't need to actually separate different groups to different objects.

Comment: Hi Richard, you are right I don't need the `data.table`.Thank you.